# How to properly include CSS&JS files installed as an NPM package with gulp?

Tags: javascript, html, css, npm, gulp

How to properly include to `index.html` CSS&JS files installed as an NPM package with gulp?

I've installed one of the CSS frameworks (Materialize) with NPM:
`npm install --save-dev materialize-css`

Now I want to include CSS and JS files from this framework to my `index.html`. They are located under `node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css` and `node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js`.

What is the proper way to achieve it, considering that I have `gulp` under my hand?

Use the full path to files in `node_modules` from `index.html` directly?

Copy them to `./dist` by using `gulp` task using absolute paths to the files in `gulpfile.js`, and reference them from `index.html` as `./dist/materialize.min.css` and `./dist/materialize.min.js`?

Any advice would be much appreciated. Sorry if the question is dumb, it's just hard to find "the right way" to solve this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up with the following solution in `gulpfile.js` (my example uses `materialize-css` as an npm package with css/js files that I want to include):

```js
const slash = require('slash');
const merge = require('merge-stream');

const globs = {
    ...,
    dest: {
        dirs: {
            css: 'dist/css',
            js: 'dist/js'
        }
    },
    materializecss: {
        css: 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css',
        js: 'materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js',
        nouislider: {
            css: 'materialize-css/extras/noUiSlider/nouislider.css',
            js: 'materialize-css/extras/noUiSlider/nouislider.min.js'
        }
    }
};

function vendors() {
    const resolve = (p) => slash(require.resolve(p));
    // prettier-ignore
    return merge(
        src(resolve(globs.materializecss.css))
            .pipe(dest(globs.dest.dirs.css)),
        src(resolve(globs.materializecss.js))
            .pipe(dest(globs.dest.dirs.js)),
        src(resolve(globs.materializecss.nouislider.css))
            .pipe(dest(globs.dest.dirs.css)),
        src(resolve(globs.materializecss.nouislider.js))
            .pipe(dest(globs.dest.dirs.js)));
}
```

`require.resolve(relative_path)` automatically resolves a relative file name in `node_modules` directory.
`slash` is used to convert double backslash on Windows to a single forward slash.